# In Scala, how do you use the value of the Future before it's used?

Tags: scala, future

I'm trying to use values generated by a Scala Future:

```scala
val x = for (i <- 0 until 100) yield Future(Random.nextInt(arraySize))
```

For each value of x, I want to index into an array:

```scala
val y = for (j <- x) yield myArray(j) // doesn't work
val y2 = x map (j => myArray(j)) // doesn't work
```

`myArray` can only be accessed with an int. How is this done with Scala Futures?

Candidate solution:

```scala
val y3 = x.map{ future => future.map(j => myArray(j) }
```

Comment: Both code snippets don't seem like valid Scala code. Why are you calling `sequence` on an ordinary vector? Why are you trying to feed the vector `j` as index into `myArray`? What or where is `myArray`? Looks like XY-problem. You probably should describe in more detail what you're actually trying to achieve, and provide an [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: No, I don't think so. myArray is some collection that can be indexed by an integer. My issue is that when I use `map` on a this collection of `Future`s, the type being mapped is `Future[Int]`. I, instead, want an `Int` so that I can asynchronously access my array.

I removed the sequence call if that helps anything. The question still stands: given a collection of `Future[Int]`, how do I use the value generated by the future?

Comment: Apologies - I've added the Future. The point is the `Random` call is some async task that produces an `Int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

val arraySize = 100
val myArray: Vector[String] = Vector.fill(arraySize)("")

val x: Future[IndexedSeq[Int]] = Future.sequence((0 until 100).map{ 
  i => 
  Future(ThreadLocalRandom.current.nextInt(arraySize))
})

val y: Future[IndexedSeq[String]] = for {
  indices <- x                                   // Future's `map`
} yield for {
  i <- indices                                   // IndexedSeq's `map`
} yield myArray(i)
```

The last double `for`-expression could also be rewritten as

```
x map (_ map myArray)
```

if you wanted it really terse.